# How to refer Geolocation field type in visualforce page from custom object?

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, geolocation

I am trying to refer Geolocation field type in visualforce page with InputField component, But it is showing the error.

**Vf page code:**

Note: here, Geo_Location__c is field name, object is object name created in apex.

**Error**:
Unsupported type: common.api.soap.wsdl.Location used in expression: object.Geo_Location__c

How to use Geolocation field type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try geo_location__latitude__s && geo_location__longitude__s